# Split employee IDs separated by comma from textbox into array and then manipulate those strings

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck with an idea for local image directory. We have a internal tool to lookup other employee's profiles and the url is url of image is like "https://internal-cdn.abc.com/profiles/images/empid=random_emp_id".

So I have used JS to get the images based on one emp_id by using html form to input emp_id and js to append the  ***"https://internal-cdn.abc.com/profiles/images/empid="+form_element+">"***  and I used document.write to show the image.

Now I need you help to write JS which will classify the input list of emp_id's separated by comma into an array and manipulate the n strings in array to append the IMG SRC path to finally show multiple images.

Thanks in advance.

This Works

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myFun(){
var imagesrc = document.getElementById("login"); 
image.value = "<img src=internal-cdn.abc.com/profiles/images/…;;
document.write(image.value); }
</script> 
</head> 
<body> <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Enter the login" required="required" />
<input type="button" name="submit" onClick="myFun()" /> 
<div id="image">Image</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

This Doesn't Work!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun(){
        var text;
        var i;
        var login = document.getElementById("login");
        login = login.split(",");
        for (i = 0; i <=login.length; i++) { 
            text += "<img src=https://internal-cdn.abc.com/profiles/images/?empid=" + login[i] + "><br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = text;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Enter the login" required="required" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Images!" onClick="myFun()" />
    <p id="images"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @sathyam1992: So are you asking how to split a string into an array in JavaScript?  Maybe try a Google search for something like "JavaScript split string"?  It seems to show some useful results.

Comment: don't put blobs of code in comments...update the question so it can be formatted and read properly. beyond that it is not clear at all what you are wanting to do

Comment: So from that comment-code, you have tried nothing relevant?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DanWhite Yes! I have no clue what to do. Sitting ducks here :(

Comment: Kindly stop down voting. I've added what I've done so far. @David  this doesn't work part is what I was requesting this community help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split an HTML element, not a string:

```
var login = document.getElementById("login");
login = login.split(",");
```

You want the *value* of the element, not the element itself:

```
var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
login = login.split(",");
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks @David